# Regex: matching up to the first occurrence of word with character 'a' in it

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to match the first word with character 'a' in it for each line. For example my test string is this:

bbsc **abcd** aaaagdhskss
**dsaa** asdd aaaagdfhdghd
wwer wwww **awww** wwwd

Only the ones in BOLD fonts should be matched. How can I do that? I can match all the words with 'a' in it, but can't figure out how to only match the first occurrence.

Comment: Is there a reason why you've limited yourself to regex for this? You can very easily achieve the behavior you want here with the programming language you're using.

Comment: I know, if I was allowed to use any language I can solve it in minutes. But my requirement is this has to be done in regex. It is a much bigger data processing workflow and for this part, I can only configure a regex string in the process. I don have control on the code in workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that the only characters being used are *word* characters, i.e. `\w` characters, and white space then use:

```
/^(?:[^a ]+ +)*([^a ]*a\w*)\b/gm
```

1. `^` Matches the start of the line
2. `(?:[^a ]+ +)*` Matches 0 or more occurrences of words composed of any character other than an `a` followed by one or more spaces in a non-capturing group.
3. `([^a ]*a\w*)\b` Matches a word ending on a word boundary (it is already guaranteed to begin on a word boundary) that contains an `a`. The word-boundary constraint allows for the word to be at the end of the line.

The first word with an `a` in it will be in group #1.

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/VtnlZu/1/)

If we cannot assume that only word (`\w`) and white space characters are present, then use:

```
^(?:[^a ]+ +)*(\w*a\w*)\b
```

The difference is in scanning the first word with an `a` in it, `(\w*a\w*)`, where we are guaranteed that we are scanning a string composed of only word characters.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using? In many programs you can set limit. If possible: `\b[b-z]*a[a-z]*` with 1 limit.

If it is not possible, use group to capture and match latter: `([b-z]*a[a-z]*).*`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
^(?:[^a ]+ )*(\w*a\w*) .*$
```

Basically what it says is: capture a bunch of words that are composed of *anything but* the letter `a` (or `<space>`) then capture a word that *must* include the letter `a`.

**Group 1** should hold the first word with `a`.